# why minlength doesn't kick in when in the initial state?

Tags: angular

below is a piece of code:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="someProperty" minlength="5" />
```

ran the app, and I used brower debugger tool to check the state of this input, and I found it is actually valid in the the initial state as I can see `ng-valid` is attached to the input control, but isn't that there is no content for the input in the initial state so that the length is 0, which clearly violates the minlength requirement? why I have to type at least one char to trigger the validation? isn't that `ng-invalid` better present the initial state?

Comment: whether are you check in constructor / ngAfterViewInit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untill the input is touched it's considered as valid for a better user experience. Anyway you can manually trigger validation by calling *updateValueAndValidity*:  https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateValueAndValidity